# What is the type of a built-in array's size?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

When deducing a non-type template parameter, say `n`, the types of `n` must match exactly between the parameter and argument. So the following code will not compile (at least on GCC and clang):

```
#include <array>
template <int n> void f(std::array<int, n> const&) {}
int main() {
  std::array<int, 3> arr;
  f(arr);
}
```

This is because `std::array` is declared as

```
template <typename T, std::size_t n> class array;
```

rather than

```
template <typename T, int n> class array;
```

However, to capture the size of a built-in array, it seems that any integral type does. All of the following work on GCC, clang, and VC++:

```
template <typename T, char n > void f(T (&)[n]);
template <typename T, short n> void f(T (&)[n]);
template <typename T, int   n> void f(T (&)[n]);
...
```

So, seriously, the type of a built-in array's size is overloaded?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Implicit integral conversion is nothing new...

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: While this is something new for the type of a non-type template parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in 14.8.2.5 **[temp.deduct.type]** paragraph 17:

> 17 - [...] [The] template-argument type shall match the type of the template-parameter exactly, except that a template-argument deduced from an array bound may be of any integral type.

In http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1770 this is improved to the more general:

> 17 - If `P` has a form that contains `<i>`, and if the type of the corresponding value of `A` differs from the type of `i`, deduction fails. If `P` has a form that contains `[i]`, and if the type of `i` is not an integral type, deduction fails.

So array bounds can be deduced to any integral type, but non-type template parameters must be deduced to the actual type in the template definition.

Indeed, there is nowhere in the C++11 version of the Standard that specifies a preferred type for array bounds; an array bound is specified (in **[dcl.array]**) to be "*an integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero*". In recent drafts for C++14 this is amended to "*a converted constant expression (5.19) of type `std::size_t` [...]*"; the changed definition can be traced to [n3306](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3306.pdf). Somewhat oddly, the change is presented as a "*consequential adjustment [..] for the sake of consistency*", implying that the editors considered it self-apparent that `size_t` was the correct type.

Comment: Considering the return type of the `sizeof` operator, I feel it is somewhat apparent :-)

Answer (score 6):

From §8.3.4  [dcl.array]/1:

> If the constant-expression (5.19)
>   is present, it shall be a converted constant expression of type std::size_t and its value shall be greater than zero. The constant expression specifies the bound of (number of elements in) the array

The type is `std::size_t`.

The reason other types work in general is that conversions are done on the type passed in according to §14.3.2  [temp.arg.nontype]/5:

> For a non-type template-parameter of integral or enumeration type, conversions permitted in a converted constant expression (5.19) are applied.

From §5.19 [expr.const]/3:

> An integral constant expression is an expression of integral or unscoped enumeration type, implicitly converted to a prvalue, where the converted expression is a core constant expression.
>
> *snip* (mentions these can be used as array bounds)
>
> A converted constant expression of type T is an expression, implicitly converted to a prvalue of type T, where the converted expression is a core constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only user-defined conversions, lvalue-to-rvalue conversions (4.1), integral promotions (4.5), and **integral conversions** (4.7) other than narrowing conversions (8.5.4).

Finally, §4.7 [conv.integral]/3:

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

If the value of the bound fits inside of your parameter type, it will be converted successfully. If not, you'll end up with an implementation-defined value for the bound.

Arrays are a special case, as pointed out in [ectamur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24826604/962089):

§14.8.2.5 [temp.deduct.type]/17:

> If, in the declaration of a function template with a non-type template-parameter, the non-type template-parameter is used in an expression in the function parameter-list and, if the corresponding template-argument is deduced, the template-argument type shall match the type of the template-parameter exactly, except that a template-argument deduced from an array bound may be of any integral type.

Comment: `14.8.2.5` fires everything :-) Built-in arrays are just as special as they always are in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The size of C array are compile time constant and are managed by the compiler (there is no info about the size of the C array in runtime), when you instantiate the template, the compiler only check if the real size fit in the template type provided. Example:

```
template <typename T, char n > void f(T (&)[n]) {}

int main() { 
  int a[1000];
  f(a);
}
```

This will fail even when `int a[20];` succeed.

Comment: Remember that's `std::size_t` from `<cstddef>`.

Comment: Your post does not answer the question. The OP isn't asking what size type containers use but why types other than `size_t` can be used in the context presented in the question.

Comment: In other words, narrowing conversions are not permitted in non-type template argument deduction.