# Segmentation fault (core dumped) vectors

Tags: c++, vector

i tried to write simple program that gets numbers fro users and then sorts them. I used vectors for the first time and got this "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" in terminal. Can smbd help me with fix to this code?
I think there is an problem in function sortowanie() with table.erase() but i can be wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector <int> table;
vector <int> sorted;

void out(){
 for( size_t i = 0; i < table.size(); i++ ){
       cout << table[i] << ", ";
   }
}

int y=table[0];
int z;

void sortowanie(){
    for( size_t i = 0; i < table.size(); i++ ){
       if(table[i]<y){
           y=table[i];
           z=i;
       }

   }
   sorted.push_back(y);
   table.erase(table.begin()+z);

   if(table.size() == 0){
       out();
   }
   else{
       sortowanie();
   }


}

void dodawanie(){
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    table.push_back(x);

    if(x == 0){
        sortowanie();
    }
    else{
        dodawanie();
    }
}
int main() 
{
    cout << "podaj liczby z przedziału liczb naturalnych \n";

    dodawanie();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? It may fail on this line `table.erase(table.begin()+z);`

Comment: Hint: what do you think the size of `table` is when you do `int y=table[0];` ?

Comment: Other hint: those global variables `x` and  `z` are very poor design anyway. Sometimes global variables can be useful, but in your case they are not.

Comment: Other hint: for sorting other than exercises on how to write sorting algorithms you should use the sortings algorithms in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: Also calling `dodawanie` recursively is very strange and convoluted. Keep it simple.

Comment: The only reason that i wanted to write my own sorting algorithm was that i wanted to come up with my own sollution just to exercise cause i am new to this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the type of a built-in array's size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826139/what-is-the-type-of-a-built-in-arrays-size)

Comment: Another problem is the combination of recursion and global variables - when `sortowanie()` is called recursively `z`might not be changed and you call `erase` to an already erased element

Comment: It's OK to write your own sort algorithm as an exercise. I had a look on your code, but I'm afraid the overall design of your code and the sort algorithm are broken beyond repair. I'd throw this code away and start over again. Don't use global variables, or maybe at most  `table` and `sorted`.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it solved the posted problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table.erase(table.begin()+z);` is definitely the problem, since `z` is not always assigned by `z=i;` but only iff `table[i]<y`. So take the assignment out of the if statement. Otherwise your `z` will increment `table.begin()` out of bounds, which leads to UB, which leads to your crash. Also you must not delete begin if the vector is empty, so put the erase in an `if(table.begin()+z < table.end())` expression, which should prevent the crash in all cases. And make `z` a local variable of `sortowanie`.